# How to search across pipeline logs

Tags: gitlab

Again and again I have the need to search for certain words, sentences or fragments of error messages across the logs of all pipelines that ran over the last few hours or days in our GitLab. Is that possible?
The search box seems to allow only for author, tags, branch name, status and source. Is there a more flexible search capability?